# How to plot rectangles aligned by their center?

Tags: graphics, geometry

Supose I have a rectangle which area is $x^2$. In some cases I may not know what is the size of each side, for $x=12,$ we have several possibilites:

```
{{144, 1}, {72, 2}, {48, 3}, {36, 4}, {24, 6}, {18, 8}, {16, 9}, {12, 
  12}, {9, 16}, {8, 18}, {6, 24}, {4, 36}, {3, 48}, {2, 72}, {1, 144}}
```

I want to plot each one of these rectangles, all them aligned by their center.

Until now, I did this:

```
n = 144;
a = Select[n/Range[1, n], IntegerQ];
b = Reverse[a];
c = Table[{a[[x]], b[[x]]}, {x, 1, Length[a]}]
```

Which finds all the sizes of the sizes which satisfy $a\cdot b=x^2$. But I can't figure out how to do the next part, can you help me?

Comment: To find all side pairs: `{a, b} /. Solve[a b == 144 && a > 0 && b > 0, Integers]`

Comment: Everyone is so busy answering.. no one votes the question up?

Comment: Gustavo, I see that you have not Accepted an answer to this question.  Did you forget or are they all unsatisfactory in some way?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Oh sorry. I forgot.

Comment: Well, thanks for the Accept.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seems too simple to really be what you're asking but perhaps:

```
recs = {{144, 1}, {72, 2}, {48, 3}, {36, 4}, {24, 6}, {18, 8}, {16, 
    9}, {12, 12}, {9, 16}, {8, 18}, {6, 24}, {4, 36}, {3, 48}, {2, 
    72}, {1, 144}};

Rectangle[-#/2, #/2] & /@ recs // Graphics
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You should also look at [`Divisors`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Divisors.html).

Comment: But what I want is really simple, also thanks for refreshing my memory on the Divisors.

Comment: If you'd like you can make my answer a part of yours - I'll delete mine then.

Comment: @Vitaliy sorry, I didn't notice your comment until now; please, keep your answer and your points. :-)

Answer (score 11):

This is based on @Mr.Wizard [**answer**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10572/how-to-plot-rectangles-aligned-by-their-center/10573#10573) , just trying to improve presentation:

First of all you can find all your sides as:

```
recs = {a, b} /. Solve[a b == 144 && a > 0 && b > 0, Integers];
```

Then lets clearly distinguish rectangles:

```
Manipulate[Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Opacity[.2], Thickness[.001], Black}], Blue, 
   Opacity[op], Rectangle[-#/2, #/2] & /@ recs[[1 ;; re]]}, PlotRange -> pl], 
   {{op, .2, "opacity"}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
   {{pl, 16, "zoom"}, 1, 75, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
   {{re, Length[recs], "number"}, 1, Length[recs], 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Try!

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[Hue[RandomReal[]]], 
Rectangle[{0, 0}, #]} & /@ c, Frame -> True, 
GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Orange, Dashed]]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, It's also a nice visualization.

Answer (score 9):

It seems I understood your requirement somewhat differently from others, so this is what I came up with:

```
GraphicsGrid[{Graphics@Rectangle[{0, 0}, #] & /@ c}]
```

[image]

`Graphics[Rectangle[…]]` plots each rectangle in list c, without any consideration for alignement. Then let `GraphicsGrid` do the alignment for you…

---

*Edit:* and I can has color too:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Also based on @Mr.W's answer and taking up his suggestion (using `Divisors`):

```
ClearAll[rectangles];
rectangles = Function[{x}, {-#/2, #/2} & /@ ({x^2/#, #} & /@ Divisors[x^2])];
grphcs :=  Graphics[{Directive[Hue[RandomReal[]], EdgeForm[Opacity[.3]], 
   FaceForm[Opacity[.3]]], Rectangle[Sequence @@ #]} & /@ #, ImageSize->300] &

Row[grphcs@rectangles[#] & /@ {2,3,4,5}]
```

[image]

```
Row[grphcs@rectangles[#] & /@ {9, 10, 12}]
```

[image]