# How can I draw a Cuboid given its center and its dimensions?

Tags: graphics

I want to draw a Cuboid accroding to the coordinates of its geometric center and its dimensions, rather than its diagnoal coordiantes. 
And How can I draw a triangular prism?

Comment: Possible duplicate, or at least strongly related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10572/121

Comment: Dear @user5463: you asked eleven questions and voted only twice. Is there something wrong with the answers you're getting in the site? Also, please change your userid for something more "human" :)

Comment: Sorry about that, I did't realise that I had to vote that much. I voted for questions asked by others, does it have anything to do with my answers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cuboid[center_, dim_ ] := Cuboid[center - dim/2, center + dim/2]

Graphics3D[cuboid[{6, 7, 8}, {1, 2, 3}], Axes -> True]
```

[image]

For the triangular prism see my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22356/193).

**Edit**

Please note that (by design)

```
cuboid[{c, c, c}, {xd, yd, zd}] == cuboid[ c, {xd, yd, zd}]
```

and

```
cuboid[{cx, cy, cz}, {d, d, d}] == cuboid[ {cx, cy, cz}, d]
```

If you want

```
cuboid[ 1, 3 ]
```

to represent a cube of size 3 centered at {1, 1, 1}, you can modify the definition as follows:

```
cuboid[center_, dim_ ] := Cuboid[center - dim/2 + {0,0,0}, center + dim/2 + {0,0,0}]
```

Comment: belisarius Thanks，Big favor!

Comment: center + dim/2 + {0, 0, 0} ??