# a table of rectangles

Tags: graphics

I have code to generate this image:

[image: divisors of 24]

But my code is awkward and clunky:

```
Graphics[
{
Hue[3/5], EdgeForm[Thin],
Table[Rectangle[{x, 0}, {x + 24, 1}], {x, 0, 0, 24}],
Table[Rectangle[{x, 1}, {x + 12, 2}], {x, 0, 12, 12}],
Table[Rectangle[{x, 2}, {x + 8, 3}], {x, 0, 16, 8}],
Table[Rectangle[{x, 3}, {x + 6, 4}], {x, 0, 18, 6}],
Table[Rectangle[{x, 4}, {x + 4, 5}], {x, 0, 20, 4}],
Table[Rectangle[{x, 5}, {x + 3, 6}], {x, 0, 21, 3}],
Table[Rectangle[{x, 6}, {x + 2, 7}], {x, 0, 22, 2}],
Table[Rectangle[{x, 7}, {x + 1, 8}], {x, 0, 23, 1}]
}
```

]

Using as many Table[]s as there are divisors is ridiculous.  I'd like to just Map Rectangle onto the appropriate corners, like [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10572/how-to-plot-rectangles-aligned-by-their-center/10583), but I can't generate the appropriate lists.  I'm also curious about a  Table of Tables approach, but I can't generate that, either.  Out of curiosity, why is the functional approach preferable to a Table of Tables?  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can obtain it with a proper combination of `Table` and `Divisors`

```
n = 24;
Graphics@{Hue[3/5], EdgeForm[Thin], Table[Rectangle[{x, -i}, {x + #[[i]], 1 - i}], 
  {i, Length@#}, {x, 1, n, #[[i]]}] &@Divisors@n}
```

[image: descr]

Image-processing approach can be even more compact

```
Image@Flatten[ArrayPad[ConstantArray[{0, .4, 1}, {n/#, 18, 20 # - 2}], {0, 1, 1, 0}] & /@ 
 Divisors@n, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Here's a `Table` of `Table`'s approach for starters:

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24};
Graphics[{Hue[3/5], EdgeForm[Thin], 
  Table[Rectangle[{24 (j - 1)/list[[k]], k}, {24 j/list[[k]], 
     k + 1}], {k, 8}, {j, list[[k]]}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I used `Grid` for this.

```
n = 36;
```

`PadRight` and `SpanFromLeft` make empty spaces.

```
Grid[Flatten@Table[PadRight[{""},#,SpanFromLeft],{n/#}]& /@ Divisors@n,Frame-> All]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Answer (score 3):

```
rng = Range[0, 24, #] & /@ Divisors[24];
Graphics[{{Hue[0.6], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {24, 8}]}, 
  Map[Line, 
   MapThread[
    Map[Function[x, {{x, #2}, {x, #2 + 1}}], #1] &, {Reverse[rng], 
     Range[0, 7, 1]}], {2}], 
  Table[Line[{{0, j}, {24, j}}], {j, 0, 8}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take on it:

```
With[{n=24},
     Graphics[{Hue[3/5], EdgeForm[Thin],
               MapIndexed[Table[Rectangle[{x, First@#2-1}, {x+#1, First@#2}],
                                {x, 0, n-#1, #1}]&,
                          Reverse@Divisors@n]}]]
```